# Slicer selection in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, nested-if, slicers, tableau-desktop

I am trying to replicate the following calculated field that was done in Tableau to a Measure in Power BI:

**From Tableau:**

```
IF [Period]=#2018-01-25# THEN
(IF [Parameter Value]='Non-profit' THEN (IF DATEDIFF('month',[pol_date],[Period])<=2 and [non prf tag]='Y' THEN 'New Organisation' ELSE 'Existing Organisation' END)
ELSEIF [Parameter Value]='Profit' THEN (IF DATEDIFF('month',[pol_date],[Period])<=2 and [prf tag]='Y' THEN 'New Organisation' ELSE 'Existing Organisation' END)
ELSEIF [Parameter Value]='Non-prof debt & Prof' THEN (IF [payment_amt]>0 AND DATEDIFF('month',[pol_date],[Period])<=2 THEN 'New Organisation' ELSE 'Existing Organisation' END)
END)
ELSE
(IF [Parameter Value]='Non-profit' THEN (IF [payment_amt]>0 AND [non prf tag]='Y' THEN 'New Organisation' ELSE 'Existing Organisation' END)
ELSEIF [Parameter Value]='Profit' THEN (IF [payment_amt]>0 AND [prf tag]='Y' THEN 'New Organisation' ELSE 'Existing Organisation' END)
ELSEIF [Parameter Value]='Non-prof & Prof' THEN (IF [payment_amt]>0 AND MONTH([startDte])=MONTH([Period]) AND YEAR([startDte])=YEAR([Period]) THEN 'New Organisation' ELSE 'Existing Organisation' END)
END)
END
```

How I am trying to replicate it in **Power BI** but to no avail:

```
 Measure = IF(
OR(AND(SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter Table'[Parameter Value]) = "Non-profit", SUMX('Organisation Table', DATEDIFF('Organisation Table'[pol_date] ,'Organisation Table'[Period], MONTH)<=2, 'Organisation Table'[non prf tag] =  "Y" ),'Organisation Table'[Period]="2018-01-25"),

AND(SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter Table'[Parameter Value]) = 'Profit', DATEDIFF('Organisation Table'[pol_date] ,'Organisation Table'[Period], MONTH)<=2,'Organisation Table'[prf tag] =  "Y" ),'Organisation Table'[Period]="2018-01-25"),

AND(SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter Table'[Parameter Value])= 'Non-prof & Prof', DATEDIFFDATEDIFF('Organisation Table'[pol_date] ,'Organisation Table'[Period], MONTH)<=2, 'Organisation Table'[payment_amt]>0, 'Organisation Table'[Period]="2018-01-25"),

AND(SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter Table'[Parameter Value])= 'Non-profit','Organisation Table'[payment_amt]>0,'Organisation Table'[non prf tag]='Y'),

AND(SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter Table'[Parameter Value])= 'Profit','Organisation Table'[payment_amt]>0,'Organisation Table'[prf tag]='Y'),

AND(SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter Table'[Parameter Value])= 'Non-prof & Prof','Organisation Table'[payment_amt]>0,MONTH('Organisation Table'[startDte])=MONTH('Organisation Table'[Period]),YEAR('Organisation Table'[startDte])=YEAR('Organisation Table'[Period]))
),
"New Organisation","Existing Organisation")
```

In the Power Bi equation, it is based on slicer selection, similar to Tableau's parameter selection. Is there any kind soul who knows how I can go about this issue?

Comment: Make your sample code as small as possible. Once you are clear on your issue, you can then write your whole code.